# Enable edge swipe gesture of UiNavigationController but hide navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I don't want to show my UINavigationController's navigation bar but that also disables edge Swipe gesture. Is there any solution to achieve this? I'm using Swift 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is from Storyboard:
1. Select UINavigationController, In "Attribute Inspector", tick "Shows Navigation Bar".
2. Then select UINavigationController's NavigationBar, and hide it from "Attribute Inspector".